# Refresh map after x minutes

Tags: mods, counter-strike

I am using amxmod and csdm for counter strike death match. When i play counter strike 1.6 death match then after 15-20 minutes my game fps goes down due to lots of blood and bullets that hits on wall. Is there any way that map will automatically refresh after x minutes. So that fps remains constant. I don't want to restart the game or map. I want that while playing game map refresh automatically on its original condition.

Comment: You just posted this same question... what's your reasoning for making a duplicate?

Comment: Sorry actually when i have submitted the previous question at the time of submission my phone goes off so i thought it have not submitted so that's why i have posted another one without checking. Sorry for that.

Comment: Stop adding irrelevant tags to your question.  They were removed for a reason.  They don't belong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to restart the map in order to get rid of bullet holes and other stuff. It's easier to just limit or disable them. Just look at your config to get the job done.

`r_decals` / `mp_decals` sets a limit of the maximum number of bullet holes. Set them to less than 20 and it will have no impact on your PC's performance and you still see where you're shooting at.

```
violence_ablood 0
violence_agibs 0
violence_hblood 0
violence_hgibs 0
```

With these you'll get rid of the blood. (The decals settings limit the blood splatter already, but this gets rid of it entirely.)

`cl_corpsestay 1` sets the time in seconds until bodies despawn.

In order to really improve your FPS you should as well take a look at other settings, like cl_minmodels, shadow, weather, etc. For lazy guys, there are a lot of downloadable configs out there.

If you find some configs and don't know what they do, [this](http://txdv.github.io/cstrike-cvarlist/) is a good cvar list for reference.

Comment: Thanks. I will try these settings. I was wondering that there may be any amxmodx plugin available for resetting the map. But this will help me. I am going to try these settings.

Comment: they are for your client though :)

Comment: :( these settings will not apply on server? :(

Comment: they help your client fps. or did you ask for server fps? (It is still helping if you have server and client on the same pc)